# Combine convert Just to AnyPublisher

Tags: ios, swift, combine

How to convert `Just<[Int]>` to `AnyPublisher<[Int], Error>`. When I use `eraseToAnyPublisher()` the type is `AnyPublisher<[Int], Never>` which is not the same as `AnyPublisher<[Int], Error>`

For example I have a simple function which I want to mock temporary

```
func getAllIds() -> AnyPublisher<[Int], Error> {
    return Just<[Int]>([]).eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Use `.setFailureType`.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use `.setFailureType`. The situation you are in is exactly what it is for:

```
Just([Int]())
    .setFailureType(to: Error.self)
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

Comment: And this is easier than Rx? .just([])

Comment: @MichaelLong it's a little bit different) Love your articles on Medium!

Comment: I just [sic] ran into this again and had to search it again, only to find my original question... :(